# What is the best way to manage ASP.NET Identity roles and membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-roles

Now that Microsoft has removed support for the ASP.NET Web Application Management tool in Visual Studio 2013, what is the best way to manage users and roles in your ASP.NET applications?

I'm starting on a new web app, and instead of building my own system for authentication and role management, I planned on using ASP.NET. However, what is the easiest way to add roles and members without directly editing the database?

Comment: Probably use an old IDE (Vs2010) to do the configuration since you can have both on your system.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I tried using the tool in VS2012, and it said that I had 0 users. I know for sure that I have 2 users and 2 roles in the DB, and they are able to successfully log in.

Comment: You are probably pointing to the wrong database. What matters is the connection string in the web.config. Make sure the connection string are the same.

Comment: I opened my same VS2013 solution in VS2012. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest following the methodology used in the ASP.NET Identity Sample:

https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample/tree/master/AspnetIdentitySample/Controllers

They use two Controllers: `RolesAdminController` and `UserAdminController`.

Using this scheme would allow for a seeded administrative account to then manage the roles and users of that site.

I suspect you could probably just copy those straight into a new project using the new Identity scheme with very few modifications to work properly. However, I haven't personally attempted doing that part myself.